# How to document an algorithm properly with sample data?

Tags: java, php, algorithms, documentation, sql

I am wondering what should an algorithm documentation contain? Can't locate a proper guideline  to follow. I have in mind to include

- summary of the algorithm
- description of the algorithm
- flowcharts
- pseudo codes
- sample input data set(multiple)
- output data
- unit tests
- experiments

The client requests such a documentation to: *Maintain confidence in our own numbers as well as to describe our process to potential customers so they know we are taking steps to check and verify our calculations.*

- How would look like such a documentation?  (example PDF)
- What would you include more in this documentation?
- What I enumerated is that good, or this should be somehow documented differently?
- How would you search in Google for such documentation samples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some more points:

1. Performance analysis/benchmark with sample inputs and environments.
2. Alternates to the algorithm(if exists), really helps for new people, and for comparison analysis.
3. Examples of best and worst case scenarios/inputs.

*How would look like such a documentation?*
Cusotmers/Users(/Managers?) don't like PDF, they find PPTs very interesting though, at the same time business will insist on PDF. So you should have a two-level document, one in PPT just to "explain in 20 mins" and other in PDF that covers the gory details of the game.

Comment: Also if the alternate Algos are available you must compare the efficiency of both Algos.

Comment: Any samples you can show?